# Insert failing in without sharing class for a manual share record

Tags: apex, sharerecord

I am inserting a manual share record for a custom object (Request__c) and getting the error: `"Insert failed... insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []"`.

When I comment out the insertion of the Request__share record the error does not occur so I know it's specific to that insert. The class is running without sharing. The user performing the action has access to the relevant record type on the Request__c object. I debugged all the variables being used to create

**Any ideas what might be causing the insert to fail? I feel like it may be security related, but I'm not sure how to check what permissions are needed to insert a `Request__share` record. It's running without sharing so I'm not sure what the issue could be.**

Relevant code:

```
sharingToCreate.add(new Request__Share(
                    AccessLevel = 'Read',
                    RowCause = 'Manual',
                    ParentId = requestId,
                    UserOrGroupId = piwi.ActorId
));

insert sharingToCreate;
```

Comment: is the UserOrGroupId already the record owner? that can cause this issue

Comment: @cropredy thanks for your response. No the UserOrGroupId is not the owner of the Request__c record. The owner of the record is a portal user though, and that's who I am performing the action with. Would it have something to do with them being a portal user?

Comment: Which license type ?  Community or CommunityPlus?

Comment: Can you please share what is the `default external access` for this user from Sharing settings?

Comment: @cropredy The license type is High Volume Customer Portal. @Nagendra I'm not sure how to see user-specific sharing settings, but if I open Sharing Settings, the Default External Access for the Request__c object is Private. But wouldn't that be ignored, since the class is running `without sharing`? Thanks!

Comment: @cropredy thanks for your question. It turns out High volume customer portal users can't create manual share records. Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5 

If you create an answer I will mark it correct so you get credit. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by the OP, the running user is a High Volume Customer Portal user. These users have restrictions on sharing as outlined in [About High-Volume Community or Site Users](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5)

- `High-volume users can’t manually share records they own or have access to.`
- `Only share the records they own with authenticated Salesforce users in Share Groups`
- `Only share the records they own in guest user or criteria-based sharing rules`

You'll need to check the running user's [UserType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm?q=user) and avoid the insert ...

```
if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'CSPLitePortal') {..do nothing..}
```

[Apex ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getUserType)